# Laravel/Docker/Apache/PHP Server showing File Not Found on localhost:8888

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, docker, apache

So I this is probably my 5th time installing a laravel app on a new computer. The firm I work for uses Laravel with MongoDB, Apache powered by docker desktop on localhost, heroku on production. So we have a well written guide for setting up this coding environment on Windows + MacOS.

My Installation was successful it seems, until I navigate to http://localhost:8888 where it has text in the top left corner, "File not Found." If I navigate to localhost:9999, I get greeted with the MongoDB message, "It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port." This is normal so its good to see that is working.

When I inspect the page with google chrome, the console displays, "GET http://localhost:8888/ 404 (NOT FOUND)   localhost/:1

I will provide the **apache.conf** and **.htaccess** files below along with **index.php**.

apache.conf

```
ServerName localhost

LoadModule deflate_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    #Proxy .php requests to port 9000 of the php-fpm container
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/var/www/html/public/$1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public/
    <Directory /var/www/html/public/>
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    #send apache logs to stdout and stderr
    CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common
    ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public/
<Directory /var/www/html/public/>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

index.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I pulled all my files in my src folder from our github repository, which everyone has been using. Is it possible that this new laptop is preventing access for the apache/docker service?

Any input helps. If more file structure is needed, please let me know and I will add more code if necessary. Just note that a coworker recently did my exact steps on his machine and his works fine, yet mine gets File not Found.

Comment: where is your docker-compose ?

Comment: Hey Sam, my docker-compose yaml file is located one level above the src folder. So the structure is a folder containing apache [folder], installs [folder], mongo [folder], src [folder], docker-compose [YAML file]